# Do I need to turn the gas off to my water heater when doing plumbing repairs?

Tags: water-heater, leak, gas

I have to turn my water heater off because I found a leak in my wall.

Do I need to turn the gas off as well, or can I leave it on?

Comment: Did you just turn a water valve off or the water heater also?  Probably don't have to, but if not using it for a few days would turn the heater and gas off.

Comment: I just turned the valve how would I turn the heater off as well? I can turn the gas off with the valve too.

Comment: The heater itself should have a switch, maybe on a wall or a thermostat that can be turned off.  Turning off the gas valve will work also.

Comment: Ok so I don’t have to turn the gas valve then just the source to the water heater? I turned the switch to off I’m hoping to be able to fix it by tomorrow Thursday the latest.

Comment: I've reworded your question a bit to, I hope, make it a bit more readable. Please be sure that I've properly captured your question, and feel free to [edit] it again if I've missed something.

Comment: In general, you should turn off the gas (for a gas heater) or the electricity (for an electric heater) if you will be doing anything that might drain the water from the heater.  Otherwise the heat can "scorch" the heater.

Answer (score 1):

A gas burning water heater must be constructed in such a way that no gas can leak from it when the power is switched off. This means that it is not needed to close off the gas line if you switch off the electricity to your heater to fix a water leak.

On the other hand, if the gas line is easy to close off in your set-up, there is also no reason not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd turn the gas valve, the handle should be perpendicular to the pipe it controls to be closed. It should turn 90 degrees.

Comment: This would be true if the OP has a quarter-turn gas valve. Not quite so true if it's a gate valve. Hard for us to know for certain since neither a picture nor description of the valve in question has been provided. Also, the question is asking _if_ the gas must be turned off, now how.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on *where* the leak/plumbing work is. The concern is whether there is any reasonable possibility of something going wrong during the repair that will result in the water heater draining. An empty water heater should be totally off - not even a pilot light.

If your water heater is in the basement and you are cutting off the hot water coming out of the water heater as well as cold water at various places in order to work on a repair in a pipe somewhere *above* the water heater then there is very little chance of water draining out of the water heater. It won't come out through the regular hot output because you cut it off. And it won't come out "backwards" through the cold because if the water won't flow upward - no pressure. If there is still pressure because of the incoming water (e.g., if your main house shutoff doesn't work 100%...been there) then new water coming out of the leak will basically be cold water coming in from the outside - there might be some mixing but the water won't magically be sucked out of the water heater.

On the other hand, if the pipe is in the basement, or if the water heater is in the attic, then depending on the exact configuration of your plumbing system, there is a reasonable possibility that some (or all) of the water in the tank may drain out of it when you are working. If that's the case, turn off the gas to the water heater and when you are all done make sure the tank has refilled and then turn on the gas and light the pilot.